# Recurring RedirectMatch in htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

**Disclaimer:** I am not very good with mod_rewrite or regex.

I have the following in my root .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^(.+\.pdf)$ files/$1
```

What I want to achieve is that any file with the extension `.pdf` **in the root folder** will be redirected to the `/files` subdirectory.

The problem is this matches any `.pdf` on the site and seems to recur when in a subfolder, e.g.

`mydomain.com/some.pdf` becomes `mydomain.com/files/some.pdf` as expected.

However:

`mydomain.com/sub/some.pdf` becomes `mydomain.com/files/files/files/files/files/files/sub/some.pdf` when I don't want to rewrite this url at all. I am assuming it hits an infinite loop but cancels itself out after a number of redirects.

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RedirectMatch 301 ^([^/]+\.pdf)$ files/$1`

The key here is to use `[^/]+` instead of `.+` so that you don't get `/` as part of your pattern.  This isolates your pattern to only matching pdf files in your root directory.